# How to auto Concat data if some data has blank cells with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem can anyone help using VBA / Formula
I've tried it but I'm confused with what looping variation I should use for this and my excel skills are pretty much up to here :(
I hope someone can help.

[image]

I want the result as in column C

Comment: Please, [don't post a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table or use this [website](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to create a Markdown table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String
    Dim arrData, arrRes, lastRow As Long
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Load data into an array
    arrData = Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        If Len(arrData(i, 1)) > 0 Then sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        ' Consolidate data by the first col
        If objDic.exists(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = objDic(sKey) & arrData(i, 2)
        Else
            objDic(sKey) = arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Populate the 3rd col
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If Len(sKey) > 0 Then
            arrData(i, 3) = objDic(sKey)
        End If
    Next i
    ' Write output to sheet
    Range("A1:C" & lastRow).Value = arrData
End Sub
```

---

Formula in C1

```
=IF(A1="","",TEXTJOIN(,,OFFSET(B1,,,IFERROR(MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(A2:$A$100),),ROWS(A2:$A$100)),)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using functions available in `MS365` :

[image]

---

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:B8,
     _ColOne, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Fill, SCAN(,_ColOne,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y="",x,y))),
     IF(_ColOne,BYROW(_Fill,LAMBDA(r,CONCAT(IF(r=_Fill,TAKE(_Data,,-1),"")))),""))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Another formula in C1 and copy down:

```
=IF(A1<>"",CONCAT(B1:XLOOKUP(A1+1,A2:A8,B1:B7,B$8)),"")
```

`B$8` is your 'end of data'.